# Angular is finally not firing in controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I'm using a angular factory to run inside my controller, however my **finally** doesn't fun in the controller, it does run in the factory below is the code: factory -

```
var createProfile = function (profile) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.post("localhost/profile", profile)
        .success(function(data, status){
            deferred.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function(error, status){
            $rootScope.error = sitesettings.parseErrors(error);              
        })
        .finally(function(){
            console.log('hello'); // **this message logs**
        });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

and in my Controller I have this:

```
profileFactory.createProfile (profile)
    .then(function (data) {
        // **works if successful**

    })
    .finally(function () {
         console.log('fin'); // **this never fires, successfully or on an error**
    });
```

I guess I could pass my object into the profileFactory like **profileFactory.createProfile (profile, myObject)** and return it, but it seems counter intuitive.

Can somebody please advise. thank you.

kind regards

Comment: in your `.error` you are not resolving the promise as rejected and that mostly seems to be the reason

Comment: btw also try removing the finally in your $http call, just check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're returning a different promise, which you never manually resolve. If you just `return $http.post(//etc.)` it should work fine.

EDIT:

I might've spoken to soon. I missed that you were resolving in your success. But that seems unnecessary. Just do

```
return $http.post("localhost/profile", profile);
```

and have your controller attach success, error, and finally handles.

Comment: In angular, usually the combination is `then`, `catch` and `finally`.

Comment: You can use any combination of `then` and `finally`. It's promise chaining.

Comment: Not according to this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q. Their example of using `then` has 3 callback functions. Maybe you're thinking of other promise libraries?

Comment: Here's a closer link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#-q-constructor. See the second code example and the text right above it in this section.

Comment: You can even use `then()`, then another `then()` and then another `then`. The function `then` is always called on another object because of promise chaining.

Comment: `.success`/`.error` will not work with a generic promise (which is what you get with `return deferred.promise;` - it only works with `$http` promise. But you are right that this is not needed - it's better to return the original promise. Except, again, I would stick with `.then`/`.catch` in the controller, rather than a `$http`-specific `.success`/`.error`

Comment: Oh I see, a little further down, they do also add explain `catch` and `finally`. So you're right. Good call.

Comment: It was thank you, deferring the return was the issue, I never realised you lost the finally deferring it. I will have to look into this more now as I cant see why I would use the $q service?